# Sql query for calculating room prices

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have a problem i am working on for a while now , let say i have a view lets call it `room_price` looking  like that :

```
room | people | price   | hotel
 1   |    1   |   200   |   A
 2   |    2   |   99    |   A
 3   |    3   |   95    |   A
 4   |    1   |   90    |   B
 5   |    6   |   300   |   B
```

i am looking for the lowest price in given hotel for x amount of people

for 1 i would expect i will have :

```
hotel | price
  A   |  200
  B   |  90
```

for 2 i would have :

```
hotel | price
  A   |  99
```

it is because hotel B have no rooms that can exactly fit  2 persons. 6 can not be used for less (or more) than 6 people.

for hotel A price is 99 it is because i use room 2

for 6 result should be :

```
hotel | price
  A   |  394
  B   |  300
```

so for hotel A i take rooms 1,2,3 and for hotel B lowest price would be for one room 5 for 300

I did it with restriction that i will be able to fit people max in to 3 rooms and that is acceptable but my query is to slow :(  it looks something like that :

```
select a.hotel,a.price+a1.price+a2.price 
from room_price a, room_price a1, room_price a2 
where 
    a.room<> a1.room
and a1.room<> a2.room
and a.room<> a2.room
and a.hotel = a1.hotel
and a.hotel = a2.hotel
```

after that i made a grup by hotel and took  min(price)  and it worked ... but executing 3 times query that gets me room_price and than Cartesian product of that took to much time. There are around 5000 elements in room_price and it is a rather complicated sql which generates this data (takes dates start end multiple prices, currency exchange...)

I can use sql, custom functions ... or anything that will make this work fast , but i would prefer to stay on database level without need to process this data in application (i am using java) as i will be extending this further on to add some additional data to the query.

I would be grateful for any help  .

Comment: This appears to be a subset problem, which is NP-Complete.  So there are **no** fast solutions.  You have pruned your search tree greatly by limiting only to max 3 rooms, but you're still looking at exponential running time here.  A solution that works for you with 5000 records will not scale up to 8000 records etc.  You'll need to either relax your criteria more, or go for good-enough solutions.

Comment: @Stephen sorry working on it for a while now and i see no way of adding more filters i already restricted set to minimum (later i will be adding filters on country and things like that bat base query must work on all data) this 5000 rows seems to be worst case scenario though and there are around 100 hotels.

Comment: as to fastness  this query executed in 82.327 seconds  and room_price is executed in 0.171s and gives 4254 rows so there is a room for improvement and 82sec is not acceptable

Comment: the first thing you need to do is to verify whether you're dealing with an NP-Complete problem.  If so, then it would be wise to spend your time implementing approx. solutions.  You may think that 5000 records are plenty, for now, but hopefully your business will grow and your site will have more and more traffic -- become popular -- that's your goal, right?  So that last thing you'd want is for you to land a new customer with 500 hotels (IHG?), and for your algorithm to suddenly scale poorly to, say, 8000 rows, and you end up running for 10 minutes without an answer.

Comment: Algorithms that scale poorly will always get you when you least want them to be.  They'll run fine for 5000 rows, but then run for ages with 8000 rows, when you have your largest customer sitting there waiting for the demo results.  So, verify if you've got an NP-Complete problem.  If so, make modifications so that it is not NP-Complete, or implement a good-enough solution from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query itself:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
setup as (
    SELECT 3::INT4 as people
),  
room_sets AS (
    SELECT
        n.hotel,
        array[ n.room ] as rooms,
        n.price,
        n.people
    FROM
        setup s,
        room_price n
    WHERE
        n.people <= s.people
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        rs.hotel,
        rs.rooms || n.room,
        rs.price + n.price as price,
        rs.people + n.people as people
    FROM
        setup s,
        room_sets rs
        join room_price n using (hotel)
    WHERE
        n.room > rs.rooms[ array_upper( rs.rooms, 1 )]
        AND rs.people + n.people <= s.people
),
results AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT ON (rs.hotel)
        rs.*
    FROM
        room_sets rs,
        setup s
    WHERE
        rs.people = s.people
    ORDER BY
        rs.hotel, rs.price
)   
SELECT * FROM results;
```

Tested it on this dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE room_price (
    room INT4 NOT NULL,
    people INT4 NOT NULL,
    price INT4 NOT NULL,
    hotel TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (hotel, room)
);  
copy room_price FROM stdin WITH DELIMITER ',';
1,1,200,A
2,2,99,A
3,3,95,A
4,1,90,B
5,6,300,B
\.
```

Please note that it will become much slower when you'll add more rooms to your base.

Ah, to customize for how many people you want results - change the setup part.

Wrote [detailed explanation](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/04/27/find-cheapest-combination-of-rooms-in-hotels/) on how it works.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your query as typed is incorrect with the FROM clause... it looks like aliases are out of whack

```
from room_price a, room_price,a1 room_price,room_price a2
```

and should be

```
from room_price a, room_price a1, room_price a2
```

That MIGHT be giving the query a false alias / extra table giving some sort of Cartesian product making it hang....

--- ok on the FROM clause...

Additionally, and just a thought...  Since the "Room" appears to be an internal auto-increment ID column, it will never be duplicated, such as Room 100 in hotel A and Room 100 in hotel B.  Your query to do <> on the room make sense so you are never comparing across the board on all 3 tables...

Why not force the a1 and a2 joins to only qualify for room GREATER than "a" room.  Otherwise you'll be re-testing the same conditions over and over.  From your example data, just on hotel A, you have room IDs of 1, 2 and 3.  You are thus comparing

```
a     a1    a2
1     2     3
1     3     2
2     1     3
2     3     1
3     1     2
3     2     1
```

Would it help to only compare where "a1" is always greater than "a" and "a2" is always greater than "a1" thus doing tests of

```
a   a1   a2
1   2    3
```

would give the same results as all the rest, and thus bloat your result down to one record in this case... but then, how can you really compare against a location of only TWO room types "hotel B".  You would NEVER get an answer since your qualification for rooms is

```
a <> a1 AND
a <> a2 AND
a1 <> a2
```

You may want to try cutting down to only a single self-join for a1, a2 and keep the compare only to the two, such as

```
select a1.hotel, a1.price + a2.price
   from room_price a1, room_price a2
   where a1.hotel = a2.hotel
     and a2.room > a1.room


For hotel "A", you would thus have final result comparisons of 
a1   a2
1    2
1    3
2    3

and for hotel "B"
a1   a2
4    5
```

Comment: this is just typo when i was writing it down in question it is not a problem here and it would fail on select statement where i am using a1.price . anyway query looks someting like that : from (select ....) as  a, (select ....) as a1, (select ....) as  a2

Comment: @firegnom, ok, but revised other considerations on your issue

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of <> is a going to have a rather large impact when you start to look at larger data sets. Especially if the prior filtering doesn't drastically reduce its size. By using this you may potentially negate the possiblity of the direct query being optimised and implementing indexing but also the view may not implement indexing because SQL will attempt to run the filters for the query and the view against the tables in as few statements as possible (pending optimisations done by the engine).

I would ideally start with the view and confirm it's properly optimised. Just looking at the query itself this has a better chance of being optimised;

```
SELECT
    a.hotel, a.price + a1.price + a2.price  
FROM    
    room_price a, 
    room_price, 
    room_price a1,
    room_price a2  
WHERE   
    (a.room > a1.room OR a.room < a1.room) AND 
    (a1.room > a2.room OR a1.room < a2.room) AND 
    (a.room > a2.room OR a.room < a2.room) AND 
    a.hotel = a1.hotel AND 
    a.hotel = a2.hotel
```

It appears to return the same results, but I'm not sure how you implement this query in your overall solution. So consider just the nature of the changes to the existing query and what you have done already.

Hopefully that helps. If not you might need to consider what the view is doing and how it's working a view that returns results from a temp table or variable can't implement indexing either. In that case maybe generating an indexed temp table would be better for you.

Comment: sorry it only takes longer with those changes or the change is un noticeable.  Thing is i did my best to optimize this approach with multiple joins , i will probably need something else. as to showing all the view i would need to describe 10 tables and describe loads of logic , but this is not the problem here i am certain that this query is optimized and works fast i just need something else than what i've written with those 3 joins.

Comment: I think the problem is going to be as much with the view as it is with the query posted. However you can try running it through the Database Engine Tuning Advisor, and also checkign the Exectution plan to see where the biggest bottlenecks are. Maybe you can post some results based on checking these things. Let me know if you're not sure how to do either.